# refer context of another xml in an existing xml context path

Tags: xslt, xpath

ep is a xml file and /R/Rt/W/AL is a node from another xml file. Is there any way I can get out of the ep context and reference the /R/Rt/W/AL node in the template below?

```
  <xsl:template match="ep"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:attribute name="attribute_name"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="/R/Rt/W/AL"/> 
      </xsl:attribute>  
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance load the second document into a global variable with

```
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
```

and then use `<xsl:value-of select="$doc2/R/Rt/W/AL"/>`. If you only need to access the data in the second document once then can of course do that directly with `<xsl:value-of select="document('file2.xml')/R/Rt/W/AL"/>`.